# Android phone or Android tablet detection by http headers

Tags: android, http-headers, tablet, screen-size, browser-detection

Is there a way to detect whether user is accessing your website from android powered tablet or phone on the server side?

I don't own any android devices, so it's not possible for me to test what kind of headers those devices send.

In my research I found:
- many ways to detect it using javascript. But thats (IMHO) not the best moment, when you decide what web version should be sent to client. I prefer to server each version based on http headers sent by client.
- database of http headers collected and sorted by device type. But can I rely on this? Also there are paid solution that can be more realibe, but I prefer free solutions.

Is there any other solution? Can you recommend one? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mentioned this on the developer blog when tablets first came out:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-browser-user-agent-issues.html

The only difference is that "Mobile" is removed from the user agent.

**Edit**: These are the user agents for the Galaxy Tab and Flyer

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.1; en-us; GT-P7510 Build/HMJ37) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.2.1; en-gb; HTC Flyer P510e Build/HTK75C) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13
```

Comment: This is good news. If it apply for all the android devices... Can somebody confirm?

Comment: I've got access to the galaxy tab 10.1 and htc flyer, I'll update with my observations

Comment: @Marakoss I added the user agents, they both comply

Comment: Thank you for confirmation :) Is there anybody who actually can prove  we're wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/index.php) should do what you want.

Comment: So there isn't any string in http headers that differs from android phone and android tablet? It would be much easier to do regex than loading whole device database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load the whole device db but still want more reliable matching, WURFL has a cloud product now (and it has a free offering that may be suitable for your needs):

http://www.scientiamobile.com/cloud

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But it's a little expensive for the unlimited access (which we would need for all our sites). :)